# Complicated directory structure for Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a directory structure like this:

- src/name1/name1.src
- src/name2/name2.src
- tgt/name1/name1.tgt
- tgt/name2/name2.tgt

Therefore I want a Makefile pattern like this:

```
src/%/%.tgt: tgt/%/%.src
  $(COMP) $^ -o $@
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: Achieve ... what?

Comment: Patterns (`%`) do not break at directory. For you it should suffice with `src/%.src: tgt/%.tgt`. (did you mean to have .tgt-files under src-folder?)

Comment: You cannot use multiple `%` in pattern rules.  Only one per target and one per prerequisite.  As Andreas says, just use `src/%.src` and `tgt/%.tgt`.  BTW, are you sure you didn't invert this order?  Is it really true that your command wants to turn the `.tgt` files into `.src` files, and not turn `.src` files into `.tgt` files?